# Why does a text box appear behind the Bluetooth permission dialog for my Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ble

I am writing an app that requires Bluetooth to be enabled to use and there is a strange "title like" set of text that appears behind the alert dialog that asks to enable Bluetooth. The text says "Bluetooth Permission Request" in big bold letters and once the alert dialog disappears this text does as well like half a second later. Anyone know why this text is popping up and or how to get rid of it?

Here's my code that sets up the intent.

```
private void ensureBluetoothEnabled() {
    switch (mRxBleClient.getState()) {
        case BLUETOOTH_NOT_ENABLED:
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            break;
        case READY:
            showScanFragment();
    }
}
```

And this is the code that runs after.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if(RESULT_OK == resultCode)
            showScanFragment();
        else
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Bluetooth is required to use this service.")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                        ensureBluetoothEnabled();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Permissions code

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 10;

private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MainApplication) getApplication()).getRxBleClientComponent().inject(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    for(int i : grantResults)
        if(i == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All permissions are required. App will close.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

    ensureBluetoothEnabled();
}
```

Comment: can you attach an image to better describe your issue?

Comment: Just added them.

Comment: What api level is your device one? I think the issue is, it's generating a permission request to allow the app to use Bluetooth.

Comment: Target and compile SDK are 25 and my Android version is 7.1.1

Comment: As a test, try requesting permission to use Bluetooth explicitly before requesting to enable Bluetooth then once you get permission try enabling the Bluetooth and see if you still have that dialog box appear.

Comment: So explicitly trying to request the Bluetooth permissions does not create a dialog for allow or deny. I think I'm not using request permissions correctly. I'll add an edit with request permissions.

Comment: I'd like to see the request permissions code because you should always get a dialog unless you've already accepted the permissions and didn't release. You can check this in the permissions screen of you phone's Settings.

Comment: Bluetooth permissions aren't even listed under permissions for me.

Comment: I made a mistake, you don't have to explicitly request the bluetooth permissions, you just need to declare them in the manifest. I built a test app and verified that when you request to enable Bluetooth, that dialog appears in the background. I believe what it is, is a indication dialog that tells the user that Bluetooth is being enabled or disabled and will be present until the activity responsible for enabling/disabling has completed. In my test app, the dialog is only visible for a second or two, so I guess it depends on the ability of the device to turn on/off Bluetooth.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue when using react native.

Comment: I have not yet found a solution. I just ignored it basically.